# open .chm file from my.resources when a buttons clicked

Tags: vb.net, resources, load, chm

I already have this code from another question on this website.

```
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, 
("C:\Users\Beaudean\Desktop\Help.chm"),HelpNavigator.TableOfContents, Nothing)
```

That works fine except i need the location of the chm help file to point to "my.resources" where it exists because i need to install my program but in that code example it only works with strings?

Thanks you :)

Comment: Do you want to deploy the chm with your application. If so do you want to to deploy it as a seperate file. or do you want to point yor button at afile that may or may not exist some where?

Comment: i don't know if you'll get this but the answer bellow's code is good and explain things, but it doesn't work, he may of gone to bed so would you be able to help me Tony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make this work.  The .chm help file viewer is an external program, hh.exe.  It doesn't know anything about managed resources, it needs a .chm file on disk.

Setup your project so that the .chm file is available in your build directory.  Project + Add Existing Item and pick your .chm file.  Select the added file and set its Build property to Content (so it gets installed with the rest of your files) and its Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if Newer" (so it gets copied to your build directory).

And modify your code so it can always find that file:

```
    Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Help.chm")
    Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, path, HelpNavigator.TableOfContents)
```

Comment: I've done all that you said but when i click the button to open the chm help file nothing loads?

Comment: i Even tried it on another blank project to see if it's something I've done and nothing happens apart from the cursor changing to the loading cursor for a couple of seconds??? please help

Comment: This will happen when the help viewer can't find the file, no exception is raised to tell you about it.  At least check that you can see the Help.chm file in your project's bin\Debug directory.

Comment: what if it's something to do with the last line "Help.ShowHelp... is there other code that i can use just to open the help file from the startup path?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. i got it working, it was an error in your code, it was the top line i replaced it with this [ Dim path = Application.StartupPath ] hopefully this will help you to. thanks once again :)